# iOS: How do I create irregularly shaped / partially transparent & click-thru buttons

Tags: ios, uibutton

How would I create these buttons, so that clicking handles correctly?

[image]

Each button is a `.png`,  transparent outside of the coloured square.  I need a transparent areas to be click-thru.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have posted an article on how to do it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/IrregularlyShapedButtons.aspx).

If you like it, please mark me up -- I currently don't have enough reputation points to do very much on this site.

Answer (score 0):

On clicking the button, check the location where it is clicked.
Detect the pixel alpha at that location.
If alpha is 0 the disable the click else enable it. This would definitly help.